# Where are user accounts configured for the IBM Tivoli Netcool/OMNIbus ObjectServer REST API?

Tags: password, tivoli

We have an application that sends a request to an IBM Tivoli Netcool/OMNIbus 8.1 server's ObjectServer REST API. In the request, there is an `Authorization` HTTP header set to `Basic <base64-encoded string>`, where the base64-encoded string represents `admin:password`. The REST API returns the requested information, so that means the application is sending the correct password for the `admin` user.

Now I want to change the password that is sent, and I don't know where the `admin` user is configured. As you can see in the IBM management console, there is no `admin` user listed:

[image]

I tried to change the application to send the base64-encoded string for `obadmin:password` (one of the users shown in the above screenshot) in the `Authorization` HTTP header, and the REST API responded with a "401 - Authorization Required" error, so it seems the REST API does not authenticate any users listed in that screenshot.

How can I change the password for the `admin` user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Netcool/OMNIbus Administrator](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/netcoolomnibus/8.1?topic=objectservers-getting-started-netcoolomnibus-administrator) contains a database with users that is separate from the users shown in the management console. This database contains the `admin` user.

Run the Netcool/OMNIbus Administrator using the following command (in a session that supports X11):

```
<path to installation>/tivoli/netcool/omnibus/bin/nco_config
```

Then the following user interface appears where you can open your object server, load the users, and edit the `admin` user details including the password:

[image]